# Solr server suddenly stop without any Error

Tags: solr, jvm

Our Solr server version is 6.6.1, suddenly the Solr server stopping and need to start again!!

I looked to log files, but no any error or warning logged there about that!

I've increased the JVM-Memory size to 8GB to avoid memory status is fulled.

Any idea or solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Check the syslog - Solr might be OOM killed by the underlying operating system when it runs low on memory.

Comment: already assigned 8 GB Memory to JVM,but still get same thing

Comment: This isn't about the memory assigned to the JVM. If the underlying operating system runs out of memory, it will kill processes to free up memory. This is done according to a heuristic, and can often result in the JVM being killed. The syslog will usually note what happened and which process got killed.

Comment: Have you checked the exit code of the process?